# local maximum and minimum values and saddle point(s) of the function

Tags: calculus

$$f(x, y) = 7e^y(y^2 − x^2) = 7e^yy^2-7e^yx^2$$

$$fx = -14xe^y$$

$$fxx = -14e^y$$

$$fy=14ye^y - 7e^yx^2$$

$$fyy=14e^y-7e^yx^2$$

$$fxy = -14xe^y$$

$fx = -14xe^y = 0$
$$x=0$$

$fy=14ye^y - 7e^yx^2 = 0$
$$2y=x^2$$

$@x=0$ $$14ye^y=0$$ $$y=0$$ $(0,0)$ is a saddle point

Local min points do not exist, there is a local max point, but I can't find it

using $2y=x^2$ $$y=x^2/2$$
$$fx = -14xe^y$$ 
$$fx=-14xe^\frac{x^2}{2}$$

how do i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have  $$ f(x,y)= 7e^y(y^2-x^2)$$ then  $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= -14 x e^y$$
and  $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 7e^y(y^2-x^2)+ 7e^y(2y)= 7e^y(y^2+2y-x^2)$$
Note that  $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= 0 \Leftrightarrow  -14xe^y=0  \Leftrightarrow  x=0 $$and   $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 0 \Leftrightarrow  7e^y(y^2+2y-x^2) =0   \Leftrightarrow  y^2+2y-x^2 =0 $$
Thus for $x=0$, we get $ y^2+2y=0$, so that $y(y+2)=0$, and so  $y=0$ or  $y=-2$. So the two critical points of $f$ are  $(0,0)$ and  $(0, -2)$.
Now let us find the HEsian of $f$:

$$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} -14e^y & -14xe^y \\ -14xe^y  & 7e^y(y^2+4y+2-x^2)  \end{pmatrix}= 7e^y \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2x \\ -2x  & y^2+4y+2-x^2  \end{pmatrix}$$
we have  $$ H(0,0)=7\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{pmatrix} $$ this
is an inf=definite matrix, hence  $(0,0) $ is a suddle point for  $f$. 
we have  $$ H(0,-2)=7e^{-2} \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0  & -2  \end{pmatrix} $$

this matrix is a negative definite matrix, since its eigen values are  negative. Thus $f$ has a local max at  $(0,-2)$.

Comment: I see what i did wrong, thanks.